# In Alien 3 is it a dog or a bull that gets infected?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-3-1992

Everyone keeps mentioning how in *Alien 3*, the first thing to get infected/eaten is a dog. I seem to remember this happening to a rottweiler. But I just saw *Alien 3* and the facehugger killed a bull and the alien busted out of that. Did I watch a directors cut with a bull instead of a dog?

Comment: perhaps this question belongs on the movies sight? I'm not sure, is is Science Fiction too...

Comment: It belongs here, @AidanO

Comment: @AidanO I asked a similar question on the movies site and they told me to come here

Comment: @puk, strange, I thought it would be well received over there, it kind of fits in both I guess.  Good question though.  I look forward to checking out the Assembly cut soon :)

Comment: Stack Exchange has many overlaps, I for example ask a lot math questions that border on the statistical and that I need to code...

Comment: @AidanO: if you don’t think alien is science fiction I really don’t know how you sleep at night.

Answer (score 26):

If you watch the [Assembly Cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_3#2003_Assembly_Cut) on the DVD/ bluray sets (the equivalent of the directors cut, however Fincher refused to be involved), it is a bull like creature that they farm on the prison planet that is the first thing to be a host.  The dog was part of the studios considerable recutting .

It's worth watching the Assembly cut, it's far from the sequel you hope for, but a hundred times better than the release version.

Comment: I can't remember the original version but the "Assembly cut" seems to be a lot better at showing the world outside. I am not sure what other differences there are.

Comment: Will have to track that down!

Comment: The Special Edition DVD & Blu-ray section in the Wikipedia listing details the changes, over 30 mins, and generally the film makes much more sense.

Comment: My Alien quadrillogy DVD set has all the versions and I do recall the cow-like creature being first in one of the cuts. The dog was definitely in the theatrical version that I saw at the cinema.

Answer (score 4):

It's always the pet dog in any version I've seen.  The dog is a pet of one of the inmates.  And when the alien busted out it was in one of the air vents, I can't see a bull wandering around the air vents!

Comment: lol it's not in the air vents. They bring the bull in from the outside after it died of 'natural causes', then one of the guys SPOILERS---- picks up a facehugger underneath the corpse and he's like "WTF is this?!?!?"

Answer (score 3):

I am watching Alien 3 streaming and a bull is infected, but the first time I watched it I recall it was a Rottweiler.

I think they changed it to a bull because it more videogenic

### Dog

[image: Dog]

### Bull vs Dog

Comment: Given lack of any sources referenced or pictures or anything to back it up, this would be best as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I've added some sourcing. It wasn't a bad answer, just badly edited.

Comment: You're a good man, @Richard!

Answer (score 1):

It was originally supposed to be a cow/ox, the cow was made & filmed but the studio then decided against it as the Xenomorph would have been too bulky and slow. That's the reason it was then changed to a dog (faster)

The whole idea was a mistake in my eyes as the CGI took a lot away from the film for me.

*Alien 3* as a whole was a great concept 'Prison with no weapons etc' just poorly executed.

Comment: Saying it is poorly executed is an opinion and should probably be removed.

Comment: @FeldpauschAll4: I think we’re okay with some opinions here on scifi.SE. This isn’t Stack Overflow, nobody’s trying to get their job done by asking questions on here.

Comment: For completeness’ sake: Most of what you probably consider to be bad CGI, actually is not. It’s *another* kind of bad special effects. ([Wikipedia on this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_3#Creature))